# If property or field is excluded when model-binding, what value will it have?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bind, model-binding

The question is in the title, actually - let's say I have a simple class like this:

```
public class Product {
   public Int32 ID { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }
   //...
}
```

When I use it in action method, like this:

```
public ViewResult DoSomething([Bind(Exclude="ID")]Product product] {
 //...
}
```

what value will product.ID have inside this action method? Maybe it will be default value for Int32? And null in case ID is reference-type? I'm just interested, didn't find it on the web.

Comment: Did you attempt to test this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there will be no initialization at all, the property will have its default value.

Comment: and if it's initialized but excluded from model binding with Exclude?

Comment: Binding is not allowed for properties in the Exclude list, so the DefaultModelBinder will not attempt to bind them. They will not affect the ModelState either.

Answer (score 0):

The [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.aspx), which you are using if nothing else is specified, indeed uses `default(T)` for unbound values.

To change this, you can modify binding behavior per-parameter in action methods (as you are doing with the `BindAttribute` in your example), or per-type in eg. Global.asax.